# AutoScrolling in Tableviewcell

Tags: iphone, autoscroll

```
-(IBAction)_clickautoscroll:(id)sender
{
    NSTimer *autoscrollTimer;
    if (autoscrollTimer == nil) { 
        autoscrollTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(55.0/1000.0) 
                                                           target:self 
                                                         selector:@selector(autoscrollTimerFired:)  
                                                         userInfo:nil  
                                                          repeats:YES]; 
    }
}
- (void)autoscrollTimerFired:(NSTimer*)timer { 
    CGPoint scrollPoint = self.table.contentOffset; 
    scrollPoint = CGPointMake(scrollPoint.x, scrollPoint.y + 1); 
    [self.table setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:NO]; 
}
```

i have this code for autoscrolling of tableviewcell,when i click this button it starts scrolling automatically,but i want to stop this in the another button click.How to stop the above autoscrolling in a button click.
TRhanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save the reference `autoscrollTimer`, and then use `NSTimer`'s `invalidate` method to kill the timer. Or, alternately, as suggested, use `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:` instead.

Comment: i implement the Invlidate method in another button click to stop the autoscroll,it works fine,but after that i click the autoscroll button it is not working.

Comment: That's because invalidate doesn't `nil` the timer. And you're code initializes and restarts the timer IF it's nil. So, go ahead an nil the timer (when it's invalidated) as well, or change your `_clickautoscroll` method appropriately.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:` instead:

```
[self.table scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:toRow inSection:someSection] 
                  atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
```

Here, you can scroll to the next row by doing something like `toRow + 1`, and maybe somewhere in there throw in an increment statement.

Comment: sir,what is torow and some section?

Comment: **`toRow`** is the row you want to scroll to. **`inSection`** is the section that `toRow` is in.